# Merge sorting multiple files which have variable word counts

Tags: java, file, sorting, merge

I am splitting a 10 GB file into multiple files of 100000 + few hundred words(since I read upto the line when I encounter 100000 words).

```
private void splitInputFile(String path) {
    try{
        File file=new File(path);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String temp;
        temp = br.readLine();
        String fileName="fileName";
        int fileCount = 1;
        while(temp!=null){
                //TODO Read 100000 words, sort and write to a file. Repeat for the entire file
            if(wordsToBeSorted.size()<=100000){
                startCounting(temp);
                temp=br.readLine();
            }//end of if ->  place 100000+ words inside the list
            else{
                Collections.sort(wordsToBeSorted);
                fileName = "fileName"+fileCount;
                fileCount++;
                File splitFile = new File(fileName);
                PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(splitFile);
                for(String word:wordsToBeSorted){   
                    pr.write(word);
                    pr.write("\n");//check if this works -> 1 word per line
                }//end of for
            }//end of else              
        }//end of while
        mergeSort(fileCount);
    }//end of try
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void startCounting(String sb) {
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sb);// Split by space
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String text = tokenizer.nextToken();
        text = text.replaceAll("\\W", "");// Remove all symbols
        if("".equals(text.trim()))
            continue;
        wordsToBeSorted.add(text);
    }

}
```

Now I wonder how to do a sorting with these files. I found out that I am supposed to do a Merge Sort. Considering the facts that each splitFile would have variable number of words(100000 + a few extra words), is it possible to do a merge sort involving files of variable word counts? Or should I follow some other approach to split the file?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to do a merge sort involving files of variable word counts?

Sure. I assume the goal here is [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). Just open up all input files (unless there are *really really many*, in which case you might have to do multiple runs), read the first word from each. Then identify the input with the smallest word, put that into the output and read the next word from that input. Close and remove any inputs which become empty, unless you have no more inputs.

If you have many inputs, you can use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) to organize your inputs, with the next word as key. You'd remove the minimal object and then reinsert it after you have proceeded to the next word.